# Image transformation by homography matrix in C++ using OpenCV (warpPerspective)

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, homography

I'm trying perspective transformation of an image using a homography matrix.

Given translation and rotation, I made a homography matrix and applied it to the perspective transformation as:

```
Mat srcImg = imread(&quot;tests/image3.jp2&quot;, IMREAD_COLOR);
Mat dstImg, H;

Get_Homography(H, srcImg.size());

warpPerspective(srcImg, dstImg, H, dstImg.size());

imshow(&quot;output&quot;, dstImg);
```

and

```
#define FL_x 1000.0
#define FL_y 1000.0
void Get_Homography(Mat &amp;H_out, cv::Size size)
{
static float H_uc[9], C[9], C_inv[9], H[9], C_inv_H_uc[9];
static float H33[3][3];
static float R[9];
static float T[3];
static float n[3];
static float d;
static float nTd[9];
static float phi, the, psi;

n[0] = n[1] = 0.0;
n[2] = -1.0;

T[0] = -500;
T[1] = -500;
T[2] = 0.0;

d = 100.0;

phi = 0.0*D2R;
the = 0.0*D2R;
psi = 0.0*D2R;

matMult(T, n, 3, 1, 3, nTd);
matMult(nTd, &amp;d, 9, 1, 1, nTd);

getDCM_I2B(phi, the, psi, R);

matAdd(R, nTd, 3, 3, H_uc);

C[0] = FL_x;    C[1] = 0.0;     C[2] = size.width / 2.0;
C[3] = 0.0;     C[4] = FL_y;    C[5] = size.height / 2.0;
C[6] = 0.0;     C[7] = 0.0;     C[8] = 1.0;

matInv33(C, C_inv);

matMult(C_inv, H_uc, 3, 3, 3, C_inv_H_uc);
matMult(C_inv_H_uc, C, 3, 3, 3, H);

H33[0][0] = H[0];
H33[0][1] = H[1];
H33[0][2] = H[2];
H33[1][0] = H[3];
H33[1][1] = H[4];
H33[1][2] = H[5];
H33[2][0] = H[6];
H33[2][1] = H[7];
H33[2][2] = H[8];

H_out = Mat(3, 3, CV_32F, H33);

return;

}
```

The rotations by z-axis (any value at "psi") work alright.

But when I put any value (even 1.0 deg) to "the" or "phi", the resultant image is awkward. I cannot recognize what it is.

And when I put [-500, -500, 0] to T (translation), it produces a shifted image as if it is taken in a different position (shifted in right direction), but I think -500 -500 are too big. For d = 1.0, the resultant image just shows a few pixel shift (not recognizably).

I thought my implementation of constructing a homography matrix is right, but the results are awkward.

Could you give me some advice on this?

Thank you.